# Are 'pure' horror works on topic? And if so, why?

Tags: discussion, scope

We seem to have a number of questions under the [horror](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) tag relating to works that contain **no discernible science fiction or fantasy content.**

- [Title of horror novel book where the villain is actually twins raised to believe they were one person?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126255/title-of-horror-novel-book-where-the-villain-is-actually-twins-raised-to-believe)
- [Young adult horror novel from the 90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128680/young-adult-horror-novel-from-the-90s)
- [Searching for specific anthology show](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109670/searching-for-specific-anthology-show)
- [Looking for an obscure 80s movie that happened in a neighbor's house at night](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85356/looking-for-an-obscure-80s-movie-that-happened-in-a-neighbors-house-at-night)

Obviously horror stories [with supernatural or sci-fi elements](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/does-fantasy-include-the-supernatural-what-about-horror) are very firmly on-topic, but what about horror stories that don't have these?

Comment: I don't think so. Horror is less a genre and more an extra layer on top of the genre. The bigger problem is determining if a story-id is on topic without knowing the answer.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Indeed. And the general principle would surely be that if it's revealed to be pure horror, then it should be closed. The issue seems to be that a) We're not doing that and b) There are several open questions where the OP openly admits that there's no scifi/fantasy content.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of any horror that I wouldn't also consider SFF ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor [Taylor Swift is stalking me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PCbaGipDSU)

Comment: @anaranjada I'm too afraid to click on that link ...

Comment: @RandalThor you might be defining horror as having SFF in it,  in which case the examples advice are not horror and still not on-topic.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Possibly useful example: Slenderman. Since no explanation is ever given for his existence, we can't know if he's an alien or a genetic experiment or some other sci-fi-y entity, but the most famous ARGs revolving around the character are clearly trying to be some kind of "horror".

Comment: @Ixrec Granted, there are not necessarily any sci-fi elements in the Slenderman mythos, but how could it not qualify as fantasy?

Comment: I'd say essentially any supernatural horror falls somewhere under the umbrella of fantasy. Pure serial killer stories, or "torture porn" etc, certainly don't qualify, but even the likes of Friday the 13th or The Hills Have Eyes contain fantasy elements.

Answer (score 8):

I think we should operate a simple rule;

- If a question is about a horror work that contains some element of science fiction or fantasy (anything supernatural) then it's on-topic and fine to stay.
- If a question is about a horror work that has no discernible elements of science fiction or fantasy (e.g. is simply about people being killed or harmed or scared in an elaborate fashion) then it's off-topic and should be closed.

The corrolary of this is

- Where [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions ***turn out to be*** about an off-topic work, they should be retained.

Comment: What about the first link in your question? It involves someone who thinks that there is some demonic activity (the twins are demons, or something), but it turns out not to be true. Does that count as a supernatural element?

Comment: @anaranjada - IMHO it's off-topic. The OP is well aware that there's no SFF content.

Comment: "Where story-identification questions turn out to be about an off-topic work, they should be retained" ...retained? I'm confused. Don't you mean to say they should be *closed* if they're shown to be off-topic?

Comment: @jolenealaska - We don't generally close seemingly on-topic (ID) questions if they turn out to be  off-topic.

Comment: So, Chucky yes, Misery no.